# EF6 Model First: Unable to generate database from model after adding new entities

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6.1

I created a new project and added an empty data model.  I added a few entities and properties and then generated the database according to [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424).  So far, so good.  I then went back and added additional entitities.

Now, I am no longer able to `Generate Database From Model...` because I receive an `Error 11007: Entity Type 'xxxx' is not mapped` for all of the new entities I added.  According to msdn, I can follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738478%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to resolve my mapping issue between conceptual and storage models.  However, it appears these instructions assume the entities are already present in my storage model (which they are not).  When I try to manually map them, the only two tables I have to choose from are the original two tables I created.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: I think we need to see some code to be able to help!

Comment: @DavidG well it is done in ef designer, so no code to show unless you want to wade through generated code and config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a phantom error of sorts.  I had another error with a default value I was trying to set for a datetime that appeared at the bottom of my error list.  I resolved this error and everything is now working as it should.